# Intellij Spring Boot project run configuration

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I run my Spring Boot project from the command line using `mvn install` and then `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active="development"`. This works fine but is not very convenient. I would like to start it directly from Intellij by clicking the green run button.

I tried to add a new run configuration but without success. I set "main class" and "active profiles" and tried to add "run maven goal" but the last one does not work (when I choose the working directory - the one with pom.xml - it says Maven projects not found). What should I exactly set up ? I just want to run the two commands mentioned above from the root directory of the project.

Update: here is the project structure [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dW5WJ.png)

Comment: Please refer to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-spring-boot.html.

Comment: If by green button you mean boot integration as is in STS, Intellij charges for this feature... You get it only in the upgraded version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please follow the following steps:

1. Set the maven goal by clicking the "+" in IntelliJ (circled area)
   [image]
2. Write `mvn install`.
   [image]
3. Set the VM Options as: `-Dspring.profiles.active=development`

After that it should just run fine just by clicking the green play button.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I get an error: "class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist". File application.properties is located under resources. I set the working directory in both cases to the root directory (the one with pom.xml) - maybe it should be a different one ?

Comment: Could you please share a picture of your project explorer so that i can see what folder structure you are following? and also of the Application configuration so that i can see what settings you have done? Thanks

Comment: I edited my question and put a link to the project structure

Comment: The project hierarchy looks fine. May i see your .classpath file?


Note: The working directory is the root directory where pom.xml is located is correct.

Try: Right clicking the pom.xml and open in IntelliJ. The maven project should be imported automatically.

Comment: classpathentry is:  excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources". I will put a screen shot later if this is not sufficient.

Comment: btw: I tried to edit this file but intelliJ says "This file does not belong to the project".

Comment: Yes i am also confused regarding this .project and .classpath files. They are not needed i think. Just delete these files (.project and .classpath) from the project. And reimport by right clicking the pom.xml file.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I ended up importing project one more time (this time "from existing source") and setting run configuration as you sugested on the screenshots and it works fine.

Comment: I am glad that it works out! Was strange :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This should help you get started.

[image: Run/Debug Configuration IntelliJ]